# Getting onClick to work on iPad Safari

Tags: ipad

I just inherited a website and haven't worked on website for about 15 years and am not familiar with programing for touch screens.

I have the below onClick submit code that works on all browsers (including Safari desktop on PC) that I have tested as well as using Google search on an iPad, but when  attempting to press the "Submit" button when accessing the site via iPad Safari it will not fire. I've search for JQuery solutions, but am not up to speed on JQuery.  Any help appreciated.

function submitentry()
    {
    password = document.password1.password2.value.toLowerCase()
    username = document.password1.username2.value.toLowerCase()
    passcode = 1
    usercode = 1
    for(i = 0; i

```
<center>
<form action="" name="password1">
<strong>User * * : </strong>
<input type="text" name="username2" size="15">
<br>
<strong>Password: </strong>
<input type="password" name="password2" size="15">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit"onClick="submitentry(); return true">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that any non-anchor element assigned a click handler in jQuery must either have an onClick attribute (can be empty like below):

**onClick=""**

OR

The element css needs to have the following declaration:

**cursor:pointer**

via : http://www.mitch-solutions.com/blog/17-ipad-jquery-live-click-events-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but that's probably because touch devices doesn't have pointer.

Try .live():

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitButton").live("click", function(){
        // do something
    }
});
```

Or, try this plugin:
https://github.com/aanand/jquery.tappable.js

---

I suggest you to try to avoid writing unobtrusive code such inline event handlers like onclick, onmousedown, etc because different browser work differently. Especially in touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion. Being new to jQuery it is taking me awhile to get up to speed. Below is what I got to work, so far, but still am having problems with the touch screen on iPad when accessing the site using Safari. *But it does work*, strangely, when I access the site using Google on the iPad. Strange, I think!

My HTML input statement is:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="click"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#click') .click(function(){
  submitentry();
  });
```

I'm thinking that if I use something other than `.click` it might work. Just need to figure out what. We'll see...